How to keep original order data in Primeng Table with rowGroupMode=rowspan module?
When rowGroupMode="rowspan", the table data order will be forced to use groupRowsBy="name" to sort the name.
I don't want the table to force me to sort, I want to use my original order to display.
<p-table 
[value]="data" 
groupRowsBy="name"
sortField="index" 
sortMode="single" 
rowGroupMode="rowspan" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>index</th>
            <th>city</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template 
        pTemplate="body" 
        let-customer 
        let-rowIndex="rowIndex" 
        let-rowgroup="rowgroup" 
        let-rowspan="rowspan">
            <tr>
                <td *ngIf="rowgroup" [attr.rowspan]="rowspan">
                    {{customer.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{customer.index}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{customer.city}}
                </td>
            </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>

  data  = [
    { name: 'Alice', index: 1, city: 'New York' },
    { name: 'Bob', index: 2, city: 'Chicago' },
    { name: 'Charlie', index: 3, city: 'San Francisco' },
    { name: 'Charlie', index: 4, city: 'Seattle' },
     { name: 'Alice', index: 5, city: 'Los Angeles' }
  ];

below rendered image Index is be reordered。
enter image description here
In the original data, I only want to merge the names of index 3 and 4. Not need reorder by table

You are not using Faces / JSF
